# How to speed up comparing MD5 hashes in a database

Tags: sql, xml, optimization, md5

I have a database full of classified adverts for computers for sale that have come from many different sites. The database is populated by XML files that are received from individual sites advertising, and then parsed and placed in a central table in the database.

The XML files have the following attributes for each computer: Make, Model, HD Size, RAM Size, Processor Speed, Price, Location etc.

The central database table then has the same columns, plus an extra one at the start which is an ID field for our own use.

Because the adverts are created by the public, they often place the adverts on one or more of our partner sites, therefore creating duplicate adverts advertising the same computer, and I need to identify the adverts that are duplicated in the database.

The problem with identifying the adverts is that there is no unique field (unlike, say, a car with a Reg Number).

An idea I've had is to add an extra column to the table that holds an MD5 hash of the contents of the other columns. When the XML is parsed, the MD5 hash is created of each advert and then added as a final column.

Once the records have been added (100k upwards) to the table, a query is run to identify any matching MD5 hashes but this takes too long, and often times out the query (even if the timeout has been extended)

My question then is: Is the MD5 hash route the best one? If so, how would I speed the querying up? If not, what would be the best way of identifying the duplicate adverts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use MD5 hashes to quickly identify rows and have hundreds of millions of rows of data, so I would say this is an appropriate choice.

Do you have an index on the column holding the MD5?  Note that it could be a non-unique index if you want to hold the duplicate submissions in the table, or a unique index if you want to prevent a duplicate from being inserted.

If you're still not getting the speed you need, you can consider using a 64-bit hash.  Some people do that for very high volume apps since it cuts the size of the indexed field in half.  I doubt you'll need to do that for the volume you mention.

Keep in mind that the slightest change to the text of the ad will result in a new MD5 value (even an extra space).  If there can be formatting changes, you may want to normalize the data before doing the MD5, e.g. by removing all whitespace, punctuation and consistently casing the data.

Comment: Hi Eric J. Thanks for your answer. I haven't indexed it yet, but I will try that. If it's still not fast enough then I'll try 64-bit hash. Because I add the records from one XML file at a time would you reccomend I add all the records and then identify duplicates, or identify duplicates as individual records are added? Thanks.

Comment: Making a HASH unique just screams for some obvious problems - except if you know your problem area extremely well and can't guarantee that there will be any collisions (and MD5 is way too complicated to guarantee that I'd think). Now a non-unique index should work fine - but one will still have to check for collisions

Comment: @Voo: Update: We just moved from 128 bit MD5 hashes to (extremely fast) 64 bit CityHashes (CityHash was developed by Google).  Nice performance improvement, still virtually no chance of a hash collision.  If you google 'statistics birthday problem' you'll see the math behind the probability of hash collisions for a given hash width and set size.

Comment: @EricJ. Yeah I did attend a statistics 101 class, that still doesn't change the fact that deliberately using a hash that can collide as replacement for a unique index seems just asking for problems. Just use a real unique ID and you can still use the hash pretty much the same way, but avoid problems when there happens to be a collision. A 1% chance of collision assuming a perfect hash function (which cityhash isn't) needs only `6*10^8` entries in the db - not that much today.

Comment: @Voo: A "real unique ID" is not always practical.  In our case we have a highly distributed system that handles billions of transactions a month.  Because of the nature of the work we do, we can tolerate (and recover from) hash collisions (same way a HashSet can, basically).  Different requirements call for different solutions.

Comment: @EricJ. But as I see it, you still have to compare all hashes to check for duplicates, so the only difference is that in a rather rare situation (a bit less than 1 in 2^63 since CityHash isn't a perfect hash) you'd have to query for additional data. But sure if you can live with hash collisions and false positives you can avoid that - but then the argument shouldn't be "there'll be virtually no collisions" but "we can live with collisions" - which is totally fine and simplifies the design.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like adding index on hash column can help.

Comment: + Keep field varchar(32) and use HASH index on field.

Answer (score -1):

Well since you're only interested in finding duplicates using MD5 is probably really not the best choice here. Remember that MD5 was engineered as a cryptographic hash and speed wasn't the foremost goal for this (actually many modern secure hashes are made SLOW by design!).

I'd personally implement a simple hash myself and use that. As noted by Eric J. you have to normalize your data anyhow before using it and after the normalizing step your just run it through your hash function and use this.

The simplest one would be to handle all fields as strings and just use the usual string hash algorithm:

s[0]*KEY^(n-1) + s[1]*KEY^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]

with key being usually some low prime number (iirc for a usual english dictionary 31 or 49 result in the lowest collisions, but since your hash is computed of several fields that will probably not matter). This is simple and fast to implement - and also means you use a word sized hash which should also be faster.

Anyways back to your actual problem: Adding an index (non-unique!) will be the simplest solution, but I'd test if it's faster to activate the index only after adding all files (which means the DB will have to sort the files once, but would be faster when inserting) - you'd have to test that stuff.